# Print db content into multiple textboxes without using dataset

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, sqldatareader

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
using SQL.Server.Management.Studio.2008.R2;
```

Kinda new at C# here..
I got the first row of the collumn, but how do I retrieve the rest of the values?
I have some textboxes set up, and a sqldatareader putting the first value into the first textbox `investigate1`. Right now, I have it set up so that all the textboxes are printing out the first row of that collumn.. Stuck at this part.. want to get the others in there to.. The value "a" into `investigate1`, the value "b" into `investigate2`, etc.. Thanks for looking 
My relevant code
HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="investigate1" class="hexen" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="investigate2" class="hexen" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="investigate3" class="hexen" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="investigate4" class="hexen" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="investigate5" class="hexen" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

C#

```
 try
            {

                ConnFlux.Open();

                SqlCommand CmdFlux1 = new SqlCommand("select TbValue from InvestigateValues where TbId = '1'", ConnFlux);


                RdrFlux1 = CmdFlux1.ExecuteReader();



                while (RdrFlux1.Read())
                {
                    investigate1.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    investigate2.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();// What would I have
                    investigate3.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();// to change about these
                    investigate4.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();// to print the corresponding
                    investigate5.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();// values to the corresponding textbox?

                }
            }
```

***sqldb***
Yes, these are the only two columns in this database

[image: My Sql database]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using 5 separate TextBox controls, you may want to investigate using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9283stf.aspx) control.  The Repeater control will be able to handle cases when you have more or less than 5 records in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change it this way:

Change your query...

```
SqlCommand CmdFlux1 = new SqlCommand("select TbValue from InvestigateValues order by TbId", ConnFlux);
```

And now do this:

```
RdrFlux1.Read();
investigate1.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
RdrFlux1.Read();
investigate2.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
RdrFlux1.Read();
investigate3.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
RdrFlux1.Read();
investigate4.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
RdrFlux1.Read();
investigate5.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

And there you have it, an awful piece of code that does exactly what you need. **Seriously**, look at @Michael Bowersox answer; I would be surprised if having a textbox for each row is really what you need.

**Maybe you should be doing something like this:**

- Remove the where part of your query to get all the rows.
- Use DataTable `data = new DataTable(); data.Load(CmdFlux1.ExecuteReader());` to create a DataTable that holds all the rows in its Rows property.
- Iterate on the DataTable and creating a list of objects that represent the set of data.
- Assign the list of objects as DataSource for a GridView, Repeater, DataList or other control that renders a dynamic set of data.

Is something like that, more or less depending on a lot if things.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
// ...

if (RdrFlux1.Read()) {
    investigate1.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
    if (RdrFlux1.Read()) {
        investigate2.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
        if (RdrFlux1.Read()) {
            investigate3.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
            if (RdrFlux1.Read()) {
                investigate4.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
                if (RdrFlux1.Read())
                    investigate5.Text = RdrFlux1.GetValue(0).ToString();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

In case there are to few rows in the query result, this will simply ignore the missing rows (and leave the previous content in the remaining text boxes). In case there are too many rows, the "overflow" rows will simply be ignored. The real error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.

BTW, since `TbValue` seems to be a `(n)varchar`, you can use `SqlDataReader.GetString` instead of `GetValue` + `ToString`.